# Изменить отступы используя height();

Tags: jquery

Добрый день, правильно ли я написал условия для элемента? Мне нужно чтобы при изменении высоты текста менялись отступы. У элемента заданная ширина слова должны переносится на другую строчку если не помешаются на одну строчку. Если слова переместились на другую строчку высота у элемента изменилась, тем самым отступы должны изменится.

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
$(".pro_table li a span").each(function(){
        var $this = $(".pro_table li a span");
        if ($this.height() <= 18) {
            $this.css('padding-top','27px');
        } else if ($this.height() >= 36) {
            $this.css('padding-top','15px');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На первый взгляд все правильно, но хотелось бы во-первых увидеть код на jsFiddle, чтобы все-таки понять, о чем речь) А во-вторых, функция each передает внутренней анонимной функции два параметра: index и element, освобождая нас тем самым от повторного поиска элементов. Можно записать так:

```
$(".pro_table li a span").each(function(index, element){
    var $this = $(element);
    if ($this.height() <= 18) {
        $this.css('padding-top','27px');
    } else if ($this.height() >= 36) {
        $this.css('padding-top','15px');
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое работает. Помогло!